# OpenCart options not loaded properly

Tags: php, opencart

I started to work on a project, which uses OpenCart. When trying to add new options, I get a weird issue.

I create two text options in back-end and assign them to a product. And it works. The problem is, the options are not loaded correctly in front-end. They display ok, but when I output all the variables, that should exist (specifically the product_option_id), they are NULL. I didn't even notice the problem before, but I need the product_option_id to make some modifications in the code.

When I output the options on the page via print_f, I get this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_option_id] => 
        [calc_group_id] => 0
        [description] => ####
        [option_id] => 469
        [name] => ####
        [type] => text
        [option_value] => 
        [required] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_option_id] =>
        [calc_group_id] => 0
        [description] => ####
        [option_id] => 468
        [name] => ####
        [type] => text
        [option_value] => 
        [required] => 0
    )
```

I narrowed the problem down to the product model in OpenCart (catalog/model/catalog/product.php)

and this line:

```
    $product_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.sort_order");
```

I tried this SQL statement and it returns exactly what it has to, the product_option_id too. I have no idea what's wrong, the SQL statement returns the right values if tested in phpmyadmin, but the above line of code doesn't (I outputted $product_option_query->$rows and some values, like product_option_id are empty).

I doubt I created the options in a wrong way. Or is that a possibility?
Interestingly enough, some other options (select type options) and even my created options (if set to select type), do return all values, including product_option_id.

Answer (score 2):

False alarm, thanks anyways.

The problem wasn't opencart, the problem was the guy working on this project before me.
He changed the line I had problems with in a vqmod script. Needless to say, his sql statement didn't work, cause the result were two product_option_ids, one with the actual result and one which was empty.

This will be a lesson to me. If you take over a project, always double check the work that was done before.

Comment: Im not 100% sure if this is the same problem as i had (by that I mean your code fix actually solved the problem by adding unique ID's in your installation. In my installation i sorted the problem by adding, auto index and primary key to the first column in the table. (export data, truncate table, alter table, edit first column on inserts from 0 to '' and just run the sql again).

Sounds more complicated than it actually was. PS, this was v2.1 so seems like they have not managed to fix much